# SQL: Finding Maximum of Averages with related field

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having an issue to getting `max` of averages with related field (`provider_state`).

I have a table. Which has `average_total_payments` field for payments. Every row also has State field as `provider_state`. From below query I am getting `Max` of `Avg` but I am not getting the relevant `provider_state`.

Main Purpose of this query is to Give me name of the state which has maximum average of payments, including payment amount.

mysql_query

```
SELECT provider_state
       ,MAX(average) AS max_average
    FROM ( SELECT provider_state
               ,AVG(average_total_payments) AS average
            FROM gnomics
            WHERE drg_definition LIKE '%$search%'
            GROUP BY provider_state ) AS abc
```

Please give me suggestion that what is the best way to get related field as well?

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking. You have field called `average_total_payments` but you are wrapping it in `AVG` function. So what is it that you need.

Comment: Er, ORDER BY average  DESC LIMIT 1 ?

Comment: I am finding Average of average_total_payments for all rows so that I can get maximum average of payment for a state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is "Give me name of the state which has maximum average of payments, including payment amount."  Then you can solve it like this:

```
SELECT provider_state, AVG(average_total_payments) AS average
FROM gnomics
WHERE drg_definition LIKE '%$search%'
GROUP BY provider_state
ORDER BY average desc
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand the question then:

```
SELECT provider_state, field1, field2 ....
      ,MAX(average) AS max_average
   FROM ( SELECT provider_state, field1, field2 ....

           ,AVG(average_total_payments) AS average
        FROM gnomics
        WHERE drg_definition LIKE '%$search%'
        GROUP BY provider_state, field1, field2 ....
) AS abc
```

should do the job